# Math Olympiad question: Quadratic Equations.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math, roots, quadratics

> Math Olympiad question: 
> If the equation in $x$ has real roots, then find the value of $a$ and $b$.
> $x^2 + 2(1 + a)x + (3a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2 + 2) = 0$

**Approach:**

For at least one real root:

$$b^2 -4ac \ge 0$$

So:

$$[2(1+a)]^2 - 4(3a^2 +4ab+4b^2+2)(1)\ge 0$$

$$1+a^2+2a - 3a^2-4ab-4b^2-2\ge 0$$

$$a^2 +2ab+2b^2 -a+1\le 0$$

$$(a+b)^2 +b^2-a+1\le 0$$

What to do further? I don't think a graphical approach would work, and I'm also not able to find the value which might satisfy the above. Is there a better method?

Also I'm not sure if the last step helps.

Comment: Now you have a quadratic in $a$, (or $b$), find its discriminant

Comment: Hint: The last equation is satisfied by (a,b)=(1,0).

Comment: @Empy2 Can you tell the idea behind that step? I didn't understand it. If we find the discriminant of the quadratic in $a,$ or $b$, we do get the range of the variables but how can we be sure that the discriminant would be $\ge 0$ ?

Comment: $(2b-1)^2-4(2b^2+1/2)$ has to be positive or zero, which gives you information about $b$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in the line $a^2 +2ab+2b^2 -a+1\le 0$. It should be $$a^2 +2ab+2b^2 -a+\frac 1 2 \leq 0$$ and it can be rewritten as $$\frac12 (a + 2b)^2 + \frac12 (a - 1)^2 \leq 0.$$ Now you should know what to do.

Comment: Ah yes :( I never seem to be getting rid of committing silly errors. Thanks.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the resulting values of $a,\,b$ make the quadratic in $x$ a perfect square.